# Copying row from first sheet to second sheet if dropdown value in column is present

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I want to copy rows from my first sheet "Log" to my second "Return" being that column S has a drop down value of "No".

Comment: Can you show us a piece of code done on your own? Even if it does not do what you need... And we will show you were the problem is. Does your drop down cell use a list validation for a named range? Does it use a manually written list? Do you need it to show "No", or would it be enough to keep the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the next code. No need to copy the entire row. The code calculates the last used column for the wished row and copies only this determined range. It copies the cells validation and existing selected value, too:

```
Sub testCopyRow()
  Dim shR As Worksheet, shL As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, RowN As Long
  Set shL = Worksheets("Log")
  Set shR = Worksheets("Return")
  RowN = 1 'row to be processed. 
           'If you need to copy to another row, another variable must be created, or directly write its number on destination range.
  lastCol = shL.Cells(RowN, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  shL.Range(shL.Cells(RowN, 1), shL.Cells(RowN, lastCol)).Copy Destination:=shR.Range("A" & RowN)
End Sub
```